# Explicit formulas for Stirling numbers of the first kind?

Tags: combinatorics

I am solving this problem:

> What are the coefficients of particular powers of $x$ in polynomial $x*(x-1)*(x-2)*...*(x-k+1)$?

I know, how to start, how to get a recurrence relation, but I do not know how to get an explicit formula using just $n$ (means power) and $k$ (means $k$-th falling power).

Comment: This is a question in combinatorics. The algebraic combinatorics topic is different; read its definition.  I know this is confusing, because the solution requires a lot of algebra in the "work with equations" sense, but not in the sense that modern math uses the word "algebra."

Answer (score 2):

The answer, valid for $k \geq 0$,  will be

> $$
> x^{\underline{k}} = \sum_n\left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-1)^{k-n}x^n
> $$

The easiest proof I find starts from the following lemmas about rising powers, both proven by induction:
$$
\mbox{Lemma 1 : }\forall k \in \Bbb N : 
x^{\overline{k}} = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right]x^n
$$

$$
\mbox{Lemma 2 : }\forall k \in \Bbb N : 
x^{\underline{k}} = (-1)^k (-x)x^{\overline{k}} 
$$

If we start with Lemma 1 and replace $x$ with $(-x)$ it becomes
$$
(-x)^{\overline{k}} = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-x)^n \\
(-x)(-x+1)(-x+2)\cdots(-x+k-1) = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-1)^n x^n \\
(-1)^k (x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1) = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-1)^n x^n \\
(x)(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k+1) = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-1)^{n-k} x^n
$$

> $$
> x^{\underline{k}} = \sum_n\left[\matrix{k\\n}\right](-1)^{k-n}x^n
> $$

I lied, we don't need lemma 2.

To prove lemma 1, note that it is true for $k=1$ because $x^1 = x = \left[ \matrix{1\\1}\right] x^1 = 1\cdot x$.  Then assuming it is true for all $j < k$,
$$
x^{\overline{k-1}} = \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n \\
(x+k-1) x^{\overline{k-1}} = (x+k-1)  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n \\
x^{\overline{k}} = (k-1)  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n + (x)\sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n \\
x^{\overline{k}} = (k-1)  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n + \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^{n+1} \\
x^{\overline{k}} = (k-1)  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n + \sum_m  \left[\matrix{k-1\\m-1}\right]x^{m} \\
x^{\overline{k}} = (k-1)  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n}\right]x^n + \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k-1\\n-1}\right]x^{n} \\
x^{\overline{k}} =  \sum_n  \left((k-1)\left[ \matrix{k-1\\n}\right] + \left[\matrix{k-1\\n-1}\right]\right)x^{n}
$$
and since $ \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right] =(k-1) \left[ \matrix{k-1\\n}\right] + \left[\matrix{k-1\\n-1}\right]$

> $$
> x^{\overline{k}} =  \sum_n  \left[\matrix{k\\n}\right]x^{n}
> $$

which establishes induction and proves lemma 1, thus proving the result stated at the start of this answer.

Comment: But I still don't get how to express [k n] (imagine k is written over n) explicitly, not recursively as you used it in your proof.

Comment: There is no closed form expression for $\left[ \matrix{k\\n}\right]$ analogous to expressing the binomial coefficients as fractions involving three factorials. That should not bother you too much; strictly speaking, you could say there is no closed form expression for $n!$ and it is "only" defined recursively, but the notation $n!$ bothers nobody.